# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext

Tags: maven-jetty-plugin

ON jetty 8 to jetty 9 migration when using jetty-maven-plugin, the application cannot load because of the class cast exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
>   cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the context handler from WebAppContext to JettyWebApp context.

```
<contextHandlers>
                        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                            <war>../../flieName.war</war>
                            <contextPath>/yourPath</contextPath>
                        </contextHandler>
                        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                            <war>../../yourWar.war</war>
                            <contextPath>/anotherPath</contextPath>
                        </contextHandler>
                        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                            <war>../../../anotherApp.war</war>
                            <contextPath>/oneMorePath</contextPath>
                        </contextHandler>
```

Also make the same change to your jetty-context.xml

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
```